# Not able to set the HarmonyOS SDK location. What to do?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos, deveco-studio

After installed DevEco studio. I have to setting up a new project but, Showing following error

[image]

Here I am not able to set the HarmonyOS SDK location, How to set sdk location?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the SDK location in the root like below:
[image]

More details can be found in https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-guides/environment_config-0000001052902427